# Creating a List of Lists for Three Reading Frames

Tags: python, bioinformatics

So I thought it would be cool to read a sequence at three different frames, which I have pasted below. However, I've come across a conundrum: how to make a list of lists. See, I'd like a final output that displays data of the type of frame with a + or a - to signify the direction of the read (+1,+2, +3, -1, -2, -3), the numerical position of each start codon along with its stop codon, and the length between the start and stop codons. (I am only looking for the longest ORFs) An example of the output would look like this:

```
 +1 57166..61908  4743.
```

The reason why I'd like a list of lists is so that I can take all the Starts I found in the code below, store it, then be able to place it in to the output somehow. I thought that maybe a list of lists would be the best way of getting this information from three different frames. However, I'm not sure how to go about this... could someone give me a way to start? The while loops work fine, last time I checked. Thanks.

```
def codons(self, frame_one, frame_two, frame_three): 
    while frame_one <=len(self.seq): 
        yield (self.seq[frame_one:frame_one+3]) 
        frame_one += 3

    while frame_two <=len(self.seq):
        yield (self.seq[frame_two:frame_two+3])
        frame_two += 3

    while frame_three <=len(self.seq):
        yield (self.seq[frame_three:frame_three+3])
        frame_three += 3

val = seq.codons(0,1,2)

for i in val:
    return(i)

self.startlist.append[[frame_one], [frame_two], [frame_three]]
```

Comment: Do not keep deleting your question and re-creating it.

Comment: Any advice then? I just want to help and pointers.

Comment: Give people time to answer. If they don't answer your question the first time, recreating it isn't going to make them answer it the second time. Also you should show more of your code.

Comment: This question has many problems. There is a lot of domain-specific information that isn't explained (is a "frame" just a moving window? What are "ORFs"?) You haven't shown the inputs expected (what is `self.seq`?) and your "example of the output" does not match your "list of lists" description. Finally, your code is confusing - some refers to `self` so this is presumably inside a class, but some of the code doesn't appear to be in a method. Could you show it more in context?

Comment: @user363 Did you try [biopython](https://www.biopython.com)? Could you explain which kind of input do you have? If it is a sequence directly why then use the `self.seq`? And as already said the return it is outside the defined function...

Comment: Wait, you adapted wrong code from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23621115/2886003) answer, or are you looking for something different than then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have a sequence of nucleotides from DNA and you want to know if there is any gen there in any of the three frames of the sequence. I recommend to use Biopython to do it but there are other ways to make it without using the "standard" solution. Here I present one of my own solution.

The main problem is how to get the position of the methionine and the stop codons (The length is just a rest between where are they found.). To do that we need to know how are they:

```
start = 'AUG'
stop = ('UAA', 'UGA', 'UAG')
```

The start of the ORF is the codon that codifies for the methionine and the stop can be any of the amber, ochre or opal codons.

Now we could get a list of where are they:

```
sequence = "ATATAGACATCGAATACTAATAGCATACAGTCCAAATTCGGAGCCCGACATTCTTCGATAACGACCGCTGATTATATGGGGCTCCGTCTACTCTAGGAGTTCTTGGCTGAGCCCTTCTAATTACCCACCGGGTGGCACACCAAGGACCGAAAAACCGTGGCCCGTGGGGAAAGTATCAGAACGGTACGGACCGTTTTTCCACCTCAAGGGACACCTTTGTCCCCGCCAATTATGCCAACCTCTCATAGTATTATATCTCCTCAATTTCTATGTGCGCAGTGTCTGTATGTTAGGACGCGCATGCACTGAAATGGCGATAGTGTGAATACATAGGTCATCTTGTGCCAGTGGCTGACTGATCGTCTACAAGTGACAATGCTGTGAATAACAAGATTGTGCACATGTCTAACCCGTGAGCTGGAGCTCCATAGCTATGGAGCTCCAGCTCACGGGTTAGACATTTTACAGTAGCGTACATTTCTGGCCGACCAACAGTGCATGGAGTTCAAGGCACATCCTTACTAAATTCTCCGTGTCCAGATTTAACAGCGAAGACGCTTTCCACGGACACAAGTATGAAAAGCGGCCGAAGGGGTCATTTGGACCAATGGACTGTTAGCGATACGCAAGAGTGAAAGGCGGGCGATCCACATTACAAATCCCTATCAGGACTGCGAATAAGATTTTCCTGAATATGAGTGGTGTGGACAGAGCTATGTTTTTCGAATTCCGCACACTCGAGTGCGCGGCCTTCTCAGAGTTTTAAACTTTGCCTGGGTACTGATTATTATAGTCCAAGTAGAATAGTCACTCTATATTTTTAATAGAATGCGGGTGACACCGGCAAGAGAACCGAGCATTT"

start = 'ATG'
stop = ('TAA', 'TGA', 'TAG')
stop_positions = []
start_positions = []

# Normal direction
for i in range(len(sequence)): # Create the index value
    if sequence[i:].startswith(start): # Check if there is a methionine in this position.
        start_positions.append(i)
    else:
        for stop_codon in stop:
            if sequence[i::].startswith(stop_codon): # Check if there is a stop in this position.
                stop_positions.append(i)
                break
```

To invert them we can do `sequence = sequence[::-1]` and then repeat the above code. (Note that if you do that you will obtain the index reversed)
Now we need to get which are a ORF and which not. We can do so with a couple of loops:

```
for start_ in start_positions:
    for  stop_ in stop_positions:
        if stop_ <= start_:
            continue
        else:
            print("{}...{}".format(start_, stop_))
            break
```

To get the name of the frame is simple, divide by 3 the start and the modulus is the -1 is the frame.

Here is the output of the above code, as you can see I didn't implement everything you need but it is not much complicate to add it.

```
75...93
231...245
269...290
286...290
300...306
310...317
375...381
401...406
433...454
498...522
575...576
607...616
694...695
715...763
828...835
Reversed sequence
# Note that the indexes start from 1, to get the real index do len(sequence) -index
61...62 
82...101
286...287
387...393
392...393
575...582
612...613
676...688
687...688
```

Some notes:

Check that the length is more than 1 nucleotide. One faster way is translate the sequence and get everything between a methionine and a stop code. This code works fine for python 3 if you have other versions you might need to change something.

There is much to improve on this code to get the exact result you want if you can't adapt this code to get it, you don't really understand how it works comment below, or if you have advanced or you have a **major** problem with this start a new question and wait. (I don't want to provide a direct answer to a Rosalind's problem)

Comment: I have an additional question, though. In your first "for" loop, that takes care of the first frame, right? And the second loop takes care of the second frame? Should I just add more code for the third frame?

Comment: No, what I do in the first loop `for i in range(len(sequence)):` is iterate over the sequence moving the starting position, as you can see in the line `sequence[i:].startswith(start)`. This way I can check both the position and that it is a methionine. The second loop (`for stop_codon in stop:` is to check if there is a stop.

Comment: @user363 I edited a little bit the answer, but if you have more doubts let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Some bits of advice:

1. [`return`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#return) is only used in function definitions and generators, not anywhere else. You probably want to substitute `print()` instead.
2. `frame_one`, `frame_two`, and `frame_three` are (I assume, since we can't see the rest of your code) function arguments, and can't be accessed outside the function. So, your last statement, which appears to be outside the function definition (is your indenting correct?), won't work as you expect, or even at all.
3. Again, since we can't see your code, it's unclear what `seq` is - is it another function in your class? Is it an instance of the class? Is it a class attribute? Whatever it is, make sure you're referring to it correctly in all cases. You refer to `self.seq` in the `while` statements, leading me to believe it's another part of the class - probably an attribute, since you're calculating its length. But then, out of the function, `seq` becomes some sort of instance object, calling its method `codon()`. You can't do that - try calling `self.codon()` instead.

Take a good hard look at your code, run it line-by-line in the Python REPL, and make sure it's **truly** functioning appropriately. Then, come back and ask a reasonable question, showing some example inputs and expected outputs, and describing *clearly* what it is you want to do, what you've tried so far to achieve it, and where it's going wrong, with the complete texts of associated errors, etc. if necessary. I'm a life scientist, so I know what an ORF is, but at least a quick explanation or link to Wikipedia would be appropriate as well.